# How to turn route into URL in ASP.NET MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

In a View, code like this will generate the right URL to jump to *controller*'s *action* method based on the routes in your global.asax.cs file.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("text", "action", "controller") %>
```

My question is how can I achieve a similar route-to-URL mapping outside a view, such as a Controller?  There is no Html member on the Controller class on which to call ActionLink.

Some controller actions need to redirect the browser, and I want to redirect to a controller and action **without** hard-wiring the URL into the controller, which would break if I changed the way my routes mapped these URLs to controllers and actions

Comment: i updated my response to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `RedirectToAction`.

If you want just the url, use the `Url` property of the controller - its a [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Use the [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx) method on the controller:

```
return RedirectToAction( "action", "controller", new { id = redirectID } )
```

Comment: Thanks.  What if I just want the URL... but don't want to redirect the user?